# Mongo Query Array of Objects with ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the following user Model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
        //unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
    },
    phoneNumber: { type: String, default: '' },
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'default.jpg',
    },
    // roles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Roles' }],
    roles: [String],
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8,
        select: false,
    },
    passwordConfirm: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
        validate: {
            // This only works on CREATE and SAVE!!!
            validator: function (el) {
                return el === this.password
            },
            message: 'Passwords are not the same!',
        },
    },
    passwordChangedAt: { type: Date, select: false },
    passwordResetToken: { type: String, select: false },
    passwordResetExpires: { type: Date, select: false },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        // select: false,
    },

    admissionDate: Date,

    positions: [
        {
            branch: {
                //branch al qeu pertenece el horario
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Branch',
            },
            area: {
                //area al que pertenece el horario
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Area',
            },
            position: {
                //area al que pertenece el horario
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Position',
            },
            salary: { type: Number, default: '' },
        },
    ],
    
    
})
```

where I have the attribute `positions`, that is an array of objects. each object has a reference for the `branch`, `area` and `position` that this user belongs (those are separate models).

I'm trying to create a query that can show users that belong to a certain branch and area but so far I haven't being able to create that query:

I tried with:

```
{
  "positions": {
    "branch": "60691ada4a9943d8eb562874", 
    "area": "60691aea4a9943d8eb562875"
   }
}
```

tried using the `$in` operator, the `$all` operator, the `$elemMatch` operator and so far nothing has worked.

Can you please help me build the correct query to get the elements needed.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:
testing the filter with `$elemMatch`:
[image]

it should find this element:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch`, to match both fields in same elements

```
db.collection.find({
  positions: {
    $elemMatch: {
      branch: "60691ada4a9943d8eb562874",
      area: "60691aea4a9943d8eb562875"
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7l79ucix85p)

Comment: hi turivishal, I tried that solution on Compass but it doesn't find any result. I updated the question with the result test with Compass.

Comment: Found it, thanks to your solution just had to dig a little deeper, I had to add the ObjectId('id') for the Ids. {
  positions: {
    $elemMatch: {
      branch: ObjectId('6069fd648693cbe8ec5a6cff'),
      area: ObjectId('60691aea4a9943d8eb562875')
    }
  }
}

Comment: yes for the compass you have to convert it to ObjectId, i have provided solution for mongoose as per your schema, you don't need to convert it because you have specified type as object id in schema.